# Remove special characters and non standard values in a pandas

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a pandas dataframe where a column has non standard values in it.
Is there a way that i can extract or replace char and digits in the column.
I am very new to applying regex patterns to clean data.

one col is Precise_Age and second col is Browser.

In browser col i want only name and version.( if version is 10.1.2 then i want only 10)- Android 10 , Android 4 , iOS 11 etc.

[Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NW5CS.png)

```
Browser                                        desired_output
75.0.3770.143 | Chrome Dev    | Android | 9       Android 9
78.0.3904.108 | Chrome Dev    | Android | 9       Android 9
79.0.3945.93  | Chrome Dev    | Android | 9       Android 9
79.0.3945.93  | Chrome Dev    | Android | 8.0.0   Android 8
              |               | Android | 8.1.0   Android 8
79.0.3945.116 | Chrome Dev    | Android | 10      Android 10
79.0.3945.93  | Chrome Dev    | Android | 5.1     Android 5
              |               | Android | 10      Android 10
              | Facebook      | Android | 8.1.0   Android 8
79.0.3945.116 | Chrome Dev    | Android | 4.4.4   Android 4
              |               | Android | 8.1.0   Android 8
79.0.3945.79  | Chrome Dev    | Windows | 8       Windows 8
77.0.3865.116 | Chrome Dev    | Android | 9       Android 9
88.1.284108841| Google Search | iOS     | 13.3    iOS 13
```

In Age col , i want only standard values , replaces blanks , commas etc.
if age has more than 100 values then make it all values to missing.

[Age](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbooY.png)

```
Age            desired_output
67                 67
66                 66
67.5               67
60ëŒ€í›„ë°˜        60
1949ë…„            null
63ì„¸              63
83ë…„ìƒ        83
11ì„¸              11
7217861839         null
59 years           59
60ì„¸              60
73.87083774        73
54ë…„ìƒ        54
55ì„¸              55
327                null
37ë…„ìƒ        37
642                null
523                null
0.61               0
53ì„¸              53
42ë…„ìƒ        42
757575             null
91.98192554        91
1.11991            1
83ì„¸(ë§Œ82ì„¸)    83
4324234            null
8827               null
11 Years           11
```

Comment: Kindly check the image link for desired output for browser and Age in blue color

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: Please do not include images in your question, but rather a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Toto I didn't know how to clean browser col and age because these col has many non standard values present.. I want desired output as i mentioned corresponding to these cols.Help me out how to write code for achieving desired output

Comment: @LeoE Thanx for your suggestion.. I will take care next time while asking questions

Answer (score 0):

After [split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) the `Browser` column using `|` as separator, you can extract or replace char and digits in the column using the [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to transform the data the way you need. Join the last two columns to obtain the desired output of this frame.

The same principle used earlier can be applied again to replace data on the column `Age`, now using the `re.sub` as the `map` function to get only "the standard values".

```
import pandas as pd
import re

br = pd.read_csv("browser.csv")
age = pd.read_csv("age.csv")

br = br.iloc[:, 0].str.split("|", expand=True)
br.iloc[:, -2] = br.iloc[:, -2].map(lambda x: x.strip())
br.iloc[:, -1] = br.iloc[:, -1].map(lambda x: x.split(".")[0])

df = pd.DataFrame()

df["Browser Version"] = br.iloc[:, -2] + br.iloc[:, -1]

# remove blanks, commas, symbols, etc
age.iloc[:, -1] = age.iloc[:, -1].map(lambda x: re.sub(r"\D+.*", "", x))

# if the number in age is up to a 100 keep it, else replace with "null".
age.iloc[:, -1] = age.iloc[:, -1].map(lambda x: int(x) if int(x) <= 100 else "null")

print(df)
print(age)
```

*Output from **df** and **age***

```
   Browser Version    |          Age
0        Android 9    |    0      67
1        Android 9    |    1      66
2        Android 9    |    2      67
3        Android 8    |    3      60
4        Android 8    |    4    null
5       Android 10    |    5      63
6        Android 5    |    6      83
7       Android 10    |    7      11
8        Android 8    |    8    null
9        Android 4    |    9      59
10       Android 8    |    10     60
11       Windows 8    |    11     73
12       Android 9    |    12     54
13          iOS 13    |    13     55
14                    |    14   null
15                    |    15     37
16                    |    16   null
17                    |    17   null
18                    |    18      0
19                    |    19     53
20                    |    20     42
21                    |    21   null
22                    |    22     91
23                    |    23      1
24                    |    24     83
25                    |    25   null
26                    |    26   null
27                    |    27     11
```